# Can't login to Django on Google App Engine and Google Apps

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, authentication, google-apps

My (empty) django project deploys just fine, but when I switch to `login: required` and set the `Authentication Type` to `Google Apps domain` I get a 500.

Sadly there doesn't seem to be any debugging info on GAE. Nor can I reproduce the error locally. I checked the domain name I entered twice.

Any lucky guesses?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem.

Looking into the AppEngine logs it discovered this:

```
Authentication for the Google Apps domain example.com can only be performed when requests are served from a subdomain of that domain or it has been approved through the Google Apps Control Panel. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth
```

The solution is discribed here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth#AppspotDomainAuth